# Implementation of similar search function using sequelize mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

I am implementing similar search function using **`sequelize`**, **`mysql`**.

Here is the code I wrote to implement the function.

```
router.get('/:tag', async (req, res, next) => { // loadHashtagPostsAPI / GET /hashtag/1  
  try {
    const where = {
      [Op.or]: [
        // I want the searched word to be included in the title (title) and body (desc) of the post
        { title: { [Op.like]: `%${decodeURIComponent(req.params.tag)}%` } },
        { desc: { [Op.like]: `%${decodeURIComponent(req.params.tag)}%` } },
      ],
    };
    if (parseInt(req.query.lastId, 10)) {
      where.id = { [Op.lt]: parseInt(req.query.lastId, 10)};      
    }    
    const posts = await Post.findAll({
      where,
      limit: 10,      
      order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],      
      include: [{
        model: Hashtag,
        // Also, I would like to implement a similar search function in the hash tag table.
        where: { name: decodeURIComponent(req.params.tag) },                                
      }, {
        model: User,
        attributes: ['id', 'nickname'],
      }, {
        model: User,
        as: 'Likers',
        attributes: ['id'],
      }, {
        model: Comment,
        include: [{
          model: User,
          attributes: ['id', 'nickname'],
        }],
      }, {
        model: Image,
      }]
    });
    res.status(200).json(posts);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    next(error);
  }
});
```

The result of executing the code did not return any data contrary to my expectation, and only the following error occurred.

```
Error: Invalid value Symbol(or)
    at Object.escape (C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop\Recipe.io\prepare\back\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sql-string.js:52:11)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator.escape (C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop\Recipe.io\prepare\back\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:709:22)
    at C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop\Recipe.io\prepare\back\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1908:71
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator._whereParseSingleValueObject (C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop\Recipe.io\prepare\back\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1908:52)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator.whereItemQuery (C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop\Recipe.io\prepare\back\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1724:19)
    at C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop\Recipe.io\prepare\back\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1649:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator.whereItemsQuery (C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop\Recipe.io\prepare\back\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1647:35)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator.getWhereConditions (C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop\Recipe.io\prepare\back\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1990:19)
```

Can I know which part is wrong in order to solve the error and implement the similar search function?